# Wordpress - How to list most commented posts in certain categories

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to add a top ten type list to my WP website.

I currently have the following but I need to be able to make it get posts from multiple category IDs, does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<div>
<?php
$args=array(
  'cat' => 75, // this is category ID
  'orderby' => 'comment_count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 10, // how much post you want to display
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php }

wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code on a dev site of mine and it does what you are wanting; however, with WP_DEBUG set to true, I get an error indicating that the parameter `caller_get_posts` is deprecated in 3.1. Depending on your PHP setup and server config, this could cause problems for you. I would suggest making the following change:

```
<div>
<?php
$args=array(
  'cat' => 75, // this is category ID
  'orderby' => 'comment_count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 10, // how much post you want to display
  'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php }

wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

With the only change being substituting `ignore_sticky_posts` for `caller_get_posts`.